# Does the arithmetic mean of small terms always converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Let : $a_i \in [0,1]$, then does the arithmetic mean of the $a_i$ converge, so do we have :

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=0}^n a_i}{n} \in \mathbb{R} $$

So far what I can say is that if the sequence $a_i$ converges then the A.M converges by Cesaro theorem.

Moreover all the $a_i$ are such that : $a_i = o(1/n)$, and the A.M is bounded by $1$ so maybe it does converge.

More generally what are the conditions on a positive sequence such that it A.M converges ?

Thank you !

Comment: It certainly does not always converge. Try 0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,.... alternating blocks of 0s and 1s with doubling length.

Comment: @MikeEarnest good catch, your comment saved me from posting an incorrect answer ;)